# why is the default replication factor 1 in cloudera 5.12 vm where as it is 3 in previous versions?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

If the default replication factor was changed from 3 to 1, then are we not losing the reliability of hdfs? How can a hadoop engineer retrieve the only copy of the block if it is crashed or deleted for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

It may be 1 in the Virtual Machine, as it only has a single datanode process. If it was set to 3 on the VM, then any files you create will be under-replicated and HDFS will not be able to repair them.

On a real cluster with many datanodes, the default should be 3.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen ODonnell. Even i thought the same but just wanted to clarify. In cloudera VM 4.7 version the default replication factor was 3 and in 5.12 version it was  1, so i was just confused about whether its the cloudera team than changed this for the purpose of VM or whether it was changed from 3 to 1 everywhere. Anyways, now my doubt is clarified. Thank you.